# Movie : Humanity found the cure for old age, but some people that used it turn into monkey-beasts

Tags: story-identification

I remember that 15 years ago I saw a movie where humanity found a cure for old age, but some people that used it turned to monkeys where other stayed alive.

Also, people had crystals that show something about their DNA and they were only allowed to mate with someone with the same crystal color or else their baby will turn to a monkey if he/she uses the old age cure

Do you know the name of this movie?

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but the Larry Niven and Steve Barnes novelette *The Locusts* is sufficiently similar that you might be interested in it too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Island City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_City_(film)), a 1994 made for TV movie.

> In the future, humanity develops a "fountain of youth" drug, but as
>   many people around the world begin to take it, most begin to mutate
>   into a barbaric proto-humanoid state.
>
> Citizens of the city wore a colored crystal on their sternum and could
>   only mate with other citizens of the same color, which was based on
>   the individual's genetic makeup. Progeny that resulted from breeding
>   outside of your prescribed color would have the genetic mutation that,
>   when combined with the "fountain of youth" drug, created the race of
>   proto-humanoids.

You can watch the full movie here;